# How to implement side-by-side tableviews

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm working on an app in which there is a social feed. I would really like to create a custom view with two tableViews side-by-side. I want to know how you would code this. Is it possible to intercept the scrolling of a table to move the other one at the exact time? Or maybe there is an easier way to achieve this?

I always say the is no limit in programming but the programmer limits. Here's mine.

Thank you for your ideas!

This what I want to do :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be implemented with a `UICollectionView`.

This should help you a good deal: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/waterfallcollectionview

Answer (score 2):

### Assuming:

1. Your `UITableView` objects are called:

   - `tableView1`
   - `tableView2`
2. You've hooked their delegates properly

   - `[tableView1 setDelegate:self];`
   - `[tableView2 setDelegate:self];`

---

### Pre-Requisite:

1. Declare `NSInteger i_check;` globally

---

Implement these `scrollView` delegate methods:

```
-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView == tableView1) {
        i_check = 1;
    }
    else if (scrollView == tableView2) {
        i_check = 2;
    }
    else { // just incase you have a scrollView that you don't want to track
        i_check = 0;
    }
}

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (i_check == 1) {
        [tableView2 setContentOffset:scrollView.contentOffset];
    }
    else if (i_check == 2) {
        [tableView1 setContentOffset:scrollView.contentOffset];
    }
}
```

---

A `UITableView` internally uses a `UIScrollView` and since the `UITableViewDelegate` publicly declares `UIScrollViewDelegate`, you can access all the `scrollView` delegate methods by simply setting the `tableView` object delegate (*which you will be doing anyways*)